# VBA : Insert function command crashing on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

For any function created in VBA, even the easiest one, I cannot use them using the "insert function" (fx). Excel shut down every time.

Message from exec terminal : "Warning: Column selection is not supported in view-based table and outline views"

**Insert function command**

[image: insert function command]

**Exemple of function working**

[image: example of function working]

On the exemple provided, the function is working correctly and giving a result. However, as soon as I click on "Done", excel shut down.

Here are the messages that I got afterward :

**message excel shut down**

[image: message excel shut down]

**details why excel shut down**

[image: details why excel shut down]

In fact, the function is working when typing manually in the cell, it is just the insert function command that it is working, which is very inconvenient when working with functions with a lot of input.

This issue also happened colleagues using Mac, but not to all of them !
PS: Excel is up to date + issue been present since first use (5y ago).

Comment: There is no VBA code shown in your question. Please show your VBA code!

Comment: Aucun code VBA n'est affiché dans votre question. Veuillez montrer votre code VBA !

Comment: To make it easier, here is a very basic code (also crashing when inserting the function with the button): 
 
Function AddTwoNumbers(num1 As Double, num2 As Double) As Double
    ' This function adds two numbers and returns the result
      AddTwoNumbers = num1 + num2
End Function

Comment: I have entered the VBA code from your comment and it works. Then I called the function from an Excel sheet by typing the name of the function in a cell and that works too.  The I entered the function using the insert function button and that works exactly the same as typing it in a cell. All good. Excel 16.79 (23111019) Microsoft 365 Subscription MacOS 14.0 Sonoma

Comment: I also used the Formula Builder to enter the formula and its parameters and that work too. I did press "Done"!

Comment: What does this mean? *"Warning: Column selection is not supported in view-based table and outline views"* - are you trying to enter that formula in a table?

Comment: Nothing crazy. When I enter the function in a cell, it is working. However when using the "insert formula" command and then click "Done", it crashes.

Comment: What is your hardware? Mine is MacBook Air Apple M1.